# Adding PDF document to table

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I'm creating report using iText 5.1.2.
I have two PDF documents. In first I have table to which I would like to put whole content of second PDF document. Each page is separate cell in table.

My current solution doesn't always work as expected. Problem is that for some PDFs, when I add them to table, their pages are  rotated by 90 degrees.

This is what I have now:

```
//First document with table
ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Document pdfDocument = new Document(PageSize.A4, 60, 30, 120, 120);
PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(pdfDocument, buffer);
Rectangle pdfRectangle = pdfDocument.getPageSize();
pdfDocument.open();


PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
table.setTotalWidth(pdfRectangle.getWidth() - pdfDocument.leftMargin() - pdfDocument.rightMargin());
table.setWidthPercentage(100);
table.setSplitLate(false);

pdfDocument.add(table);

//other PDF document 
InputStream otherPdfStream = ...
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(otherPdfStream);

int numberOfPages = pdfReader.getNumberOfPages();
for (int pageNumber = 1; pageNumber <= numberOfPages; pageNumber++) {
   PdfImportedPage pdfImportedPage = pdfWriter.getImportedPage(pdfReader, pageNumber);
   Image image = Image.getInstance(pdfImportedPage);
   table.addCell(image);
}

...

pdfDocument.close();
pdfWriter.close();
```

I tried to use *PdfCopy* but for now I only get corrupted file.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream atiStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PdfDocument atiDocument = new PdfDocument();
PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(atiDocument, atiStream);

...

for (int pageNumber = 1; pageNumber <= numberOfPages; pageNumber++) {
   PdfImportedPage pdfImportedPage = copy.getImportedPage(pdfReader, pageNumber);
   Image image = Image.getInstance(pdfImportedPage);
   table.addCell(image);
}
```

Comment: The version of iText you are using dates from August 15, 2011. Why wouldn't you upgrade to a more recent version? Your `PdfCopy` code is incomplete and confusing. Why would you create a `table` in the context of `PdfCopy`? `PdfCopy` is for merging documents, not for creating documents with tables. Pages have a dimension (expressed as a `Rectangle` and a rotation (expressed as a value that is a multiple of 90). I don't see you take that rotation into account anywhere. Also: your problem is described in the documentation; did you read it?

Comment: Switching to new version is not an option now unfortunately.  Table is added in first document, sorry, I missed that in code snippet. I've just added _pdfDocument.add(table);_.  I saw examples for merging documents, but what I'm trying to do is to insert content of one pdf document inside table added to other pdf document.

Comment: I don't think we have many customers who are still using iText 5.1.2. Are you sure you are a customer? If not, are you sure that the context of your project allows use of iText free of charge?

Comment: This code I used in one of my university projects few years ago. Now I've been asked to investigate options to generate reports on project which I'm working on. So I dig up this code and I'm testing it. I have little time for that, so currently refactoring is not possible. I guess I'm not yet a customer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are describing is discussed in [chapter 6](https://manning-content.s3.amazonaws.com/download/d/3645210-8560-4e6d-9b03-3f9aca1921a5/samplechapter6.pdf) of the second "iText in Action" book.

See section 6.2.1, and take a look at figure 6.1 where you will see two different documents, each containing a table with imported pages.

[image]

In one of the PDFs, the imported pages are in landscape; in the other one they are in portrait.

What's the difference?

Well, one PDF was created with code that looks more or less like yours: [ImportingPages1](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-6#258-importingpages1.java). In that code, you don't take the rotation into account.

The other PDF is created using [ImportingPages2](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-6#259-importingpages2.java):

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(MovieTemplates.RESULT);
int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
PdfImportedPage page;
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, i);
    table.getDefaultCell().setRotation(-page.getRotation());
    table.addCell(Image.getInstance(page));
}
document.add(table);
```

In this example we change the rotation of the cell, more specifically, we turn it back, just like we would turn back a clock.

**Update:** as an alternative for `page.getRotation()`, you can use `reader.getPageRotation(i)`.

Comment: I wanted to use that, unfortunately I don't have _getRotation()_ method on PdfImportedPage. Is there any way to do that with iText version I'm using or only option will be to upgrade to newest one ?

Comment: Thank you ! It helps with rotation.